# Pyramid of doom in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a javascript application where I want to make an ajax call, and, if required, make additional ajax calls, depending of the previous ajax response. I managed to do this with a nice pyramid of doom:

```
    function startParentArray(id) {
    getIssueDetail(id).success(function(data) {
    var source = $("#parenttemplate").html();
    var tpl = Handlebars.compile(source);
    if(data.issue.parent) {
        nextparent = data.issue.parent.id;
        getIssueDetail(nextparent).success(function(data1) {
            $("#parenttable").append(tpl(data1.issue));
            if(data1.issue.parent) {
                nextparent = data1.issue.parent.id;
                getIssueDetail(nextparent).success(function(data2) {
                    $("#parenttable").append(tpl(data2.issue));
                    if(data2.issue.parent) {
                        nextparent = data2.issue.parent.id;
                        getIssueDetail(nextparent).success(function(data3) {
                            $("#parenttable").append(tpl(data3.issue));
                            if(data3.issue.parent) {
                                nextparent = data3.issue.parent.id;
                                getIssueDetail(nextparent).success(function(data4) {
                                    $("#parenttable").append(tpl(data4.issue));
                                    if(data4.issue.parent){
                                        nextparent = data4.issue.parent.id;
                                        getIssueDetail(nextparent).success(function(data5) {
                                            $("#parenttable").append(tpl(data5.issue));
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

getIssueDetail returns an ajax response. Is there any other more nice looking way to do this, for instance in a while-loop?

Comment: Loads of AJAX requests like this suggests your backend needs a rethink. Perhaps there should be one request and the backend figures out the nesting, only returning one response.

Comment: you could declare all the sucess function at the same 'level'. They would not be redeclared as anonymous function every time you call startParentArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this code, but this could work I guess

```
function startParentArray(id) {
    var source = $("#parenttemplate").html();
    var tpl = Handlebars.compile(source);

    parseArray(tpl, id);
}

function parseArray(tpl, parent){
    getIssueDetail(parent).success(function(data) {
        $("#parenttable").append(tpl(data.issue));
        if(data.issue.parent) {
            parseArray(tpl, data.issue.parent.id);
        }
    });
}
```

As you are doing the same thing in all success callback of your requests, this may be a nice way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are what you are looking for, I'm thinking of [this one](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). But jQuery also has one (`$.Deferred` even though it does not implement what is called [A+ promises](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md)

This comes from kris kowal's `q`

> On the first pass, promises can mitigate the “Pyramid of Doom”: the
>   situation where code marches to the right faster than it marches
>   forward.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
      .done(function( a1, a2 ) {
      // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively
});
```